# What's happening on the rest of the Quad?

Tags: killjoys

Season 5 deals with the alien entity the Lady's attempt to terraform (alien-form?) and control the moon Westerly, but we haven't heard anything about Leith or Quresh (a scene in the season's first episode takes place in an installation that *might* be on Arkyn, but that's about it)- is there a reason these bodies are overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

This has so far been more or less answered by recent episodes- in "A Bout, A Girl," a member of the Nine (the aristocratic families that ostensibly rule the quad) says that the planet Qresh has recently been wracked by food shortages and power struggles, while in the episode "Cherchez La Bitch" Leith seems to be faring better for the moment but John tells a native her home moon is next in the Lady's cross-hairs should her (its?) plans for Westerly succeed.